# How to correctly compute target variable for stock price prediction 1-day 14-days and 30-days ahead?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, lag

I am trying to predict stock price movement using different machine learning algorithms with various technical indicators as features. I intend to predict whether the stock price will go up or down 1-day ahead 14-days ahead and 30-days ahead.

I am a little bit confused about how to compute the target variables to make the predictions correctly.

So far I have computed daily returns for each firm and constructed a class variable to predict 1-day ahead.

```
data <- data %>% group_by(company) %>% mutate(ret =(`CLOSING PRICE` / lag(`CLOSING PRICE`)-1))
data$class <- ifelse((data$ret) >= 0, "Up, "Down")
```

The problem now is that I am not sure how to properly make predictions 14 and 30 days ahead.

The accuracy of all the models (SVM, RF, and DT) is very similar, around 82-85%, for 1-day ahead predictions. Is this something to be concerned about or is it logical that the accuracy is very similar for all the models?

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide what it is you want to predict at these time points and make the appropriate calculations, as you've already done for the 1 day interval. Some options: you could do similar to your 1 day interval - calculate whether the closing price at day 14 or 30 is above or below the closing price on day 0, then try to predict a binary response of "up" or "down". Or you could calculate the actual difference in price between those days and use that as your response - this would be a regression problem rather than a binary classification one. However you decide to calculate your response, you then calculate the same metric in your training data and use that to train your models.

It's not unusual for different models to offer similar accuracy, especially if you've taken time to tune them all before testing. Do make sure you test against some unseen data, as some models are more prone to over-fitting than others.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I want to predict if the stock price will be higher or lower 14 and 30 days ahead with respect to today's price. So it would be a binary classification problem. 

I tried that approach when using decision trees. Weirdly, the accuracy was higher for both 14 and 30 days. I can't imagine that this would be the case if it was correctly done? It would rather be the opposite I would assume.

Comment: Intuitively you would expect predictions further into the future to be less accurate. What is your training data - are you using one record per stock, or multiple time points? If it's the latter then your data points aren't independent from each other and this can cause issues. How have you tested your models? Has it just been tested against the training data, or have you tried testing against previously unseen stocks?

Comment: Exactly. This is how I computed the class variable for 14 days ahead. Is it correct or wrong?

`data <- data %>% group_by(company) %>%
  mutate(class = (ifelse(`CLOSING PRICE` - lag(`CLOSING PRICE`, n = 14L) >=0, "Up", "Down")))`

By constructing the class variable this way, I get about 95% accuracy in my test data.

The data is daily stock price for about 100 stocks. The models have been tested on my testing data.

Comment: Based on your code it looks like you're working with a long table, with closing prices at each date. Are you therefore producing multiple responses for each of your 100 stocks, or are you just selecting one of them per stock? If you have 100 stocks you should have no more than 100 data points. If you're using multiple responses per stock you have to account for the non-independence.

Comment: Yes, my data is in long format with closing prices at each date.  I am not quite sure if I understand what you mean, I am sorry.

I do the following after I have constructed the class:

dt.model <- rpart(class ~. -Date -company -class, data = train, cp = 0.0001)

dt.pred <- predict(dt.model, test1, type = "class")

printcp(dt.model)

bestcp <- dt.model$cptable[which.min(dt.model$cptable[,"xerror"]),"CP"]

pruned.dt.model <- prune(dt.model, cp = bestcp) 

dt.pred_crisis_pruned = predict(pruned.dt.model, test1, type="class")

And then I make a confusionmatrix to get the accuracy.

Comment: Maybe you can see from the code i provided if I do something wrong?

What do you mean by "multiple responses for each of the 100 stocks"?

Comment: How many data points are in `class`? It sounds like you end up with multiple `class` responses per company. These points are not independent from each other. In order to model them properly you would need to account for this - possibilities include mixed effects models (with company as a random effect), panel regression, time-series modelling.

Comment: I end up with 225395 "down", 261487 "up", and 1386 NA's when using 14 lags to compute the class. If the closing price is higher at t+14 then the class is "up" and vice versa. And if t+1 is lower than t+15, the class is "down". Isn't this how it's supposed to be?